# better way to call custom clean method defined inside test

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest fixture to convert old testcases, which has specific clean method for all tests defined within each test.. is there better way to structure clean call especially inside common_fixture.
maybe there should be something using `request.node` parameter.

```
# test_foo.py

class TestFoo:
    def test_Foo1(self, common_fixture):
        def setup():
            print("setup")

        def execute():
            print("execute")

        def clean():
            print("execute")

        
        try:
            setup()
            execute()
        finally:
            clean()

# conftest.py
# I'm trying to move this clean method call inside fixture


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="common_fixture")
def common_fixture( request):

    logging.info(" started...")

    yield 
    # teardown method

    # TODO perform clean_up if it's defined in test function
    if hasattr(request.node.function, "clean"):
        request.node.function.clean()
```

is there any better way to structure clean() call.. or what we're doing is fine? also, clean() method has specific logic in each test case.

I tried using request.node parameter inside fixture..

```
    if hasattr(request.node.function, "clean"):
        request.node.function.clean()
```